# Is there a way to make the VS C++ autocomplete simpler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete

It seems that all C++ functions get a very accurate yet useless autocomplete. For example see the following picture:
[image: Example]

99.99% of the time I don't care much for the exact template definition of the function - I just want the parameter, like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

Is there a way to simplify the VS autocomplete?

EDIT: Sorry for the small picture, that's  the standard SO size (It kinda demonstrates my point though, doesn't it?)

Comment: Perhaps you could use some other editor, and compile using VS in command line....

Comment: It's a very common bug in C++ tools: they expand typedefs and default template parameters, to the point of exposing implementation details. (It's a bug because you used `std::string`, and UX dictates that a computer program should not arbitrarily substitute synonyms for the terms that you used.)

Comment: Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) often has better auto-complete than VS. It's not for free , but they have a trial.

Comment: I use VA, but I get the same auto-complete